# Can I disable the white "circles" to resize the image?

Tags: microsoft-word

I work with very small images and these white circles are a disturbance in that case. Any tipp would be appreciated.

[image: Pic]

Comment: It would help if you mentioned the program that screenshot is from! I'm guessing Microsoft Word?

Comment: @wrecclesham sorry, yes right, its Microsoft Word

Comment: What sorts of edits are you trying to make to the images within Word? Would it be possible to move some of your workflow to MS Paint or Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft do not provide a mechanism with which to disable the image resizing handles in Microsoft Word.

They are necessary in order to be able to manipulate an image.

[image]